# How to perform a segue from pinch (or other continuous) gestures?

Tags: ios, swift

Apologies if this is really obvious and I'm missing something..

I have a View Controller containing a UIImageView. When someone pinches out, I'd like to segue to another view, namely the index of all the images they had been at previously (is this called an unwind segue?).

For discrete gestures (tap, swipe..) I can go to the storyboard, drag on the gesture and then control-drag to create a segue.

How do I do this same thing for continuous gestures? Programmatically some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using GestureRecognizers, you can assign targets to them. Like in this PinchGestureRecognizer:

```
let pinch = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePinch:")
```

Inside the `handlePinch() {}` you could perform the segue like this: (after creating the segue in the storyboard)

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueID", sender: nil)
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks! I created an action the same way I'd create a segue for a tap, created a named segue and used "performSegueWithIdentifier" within the action. Looks like it gets called a bunch of times - so put a conditional in there to only perform the segue at the end (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 2):

**1. Unwind Segues**

In response to your first question, yes, you can use an unwind segue for that. An unwind segue is a normal segue except it's used to move back through push, modal or popover segues. It can be even be used to move back through multiple pushes, modal presentations or popovers at once.

Here's a good tutorial regarding them: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/

**2. UIPinchGestureRecogniser**

You could use the `scale` property on your `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to determine when to perform your unwind segue. For example:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    //  We need to keep track of whether we asked to perform the segue,
    //  otherwise the segue could be called multiple times because 
    //  UIPinchGestureRecognizer can be called more than once.
    var isPerformingSegue = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pinchRecogniser = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("pinched:"))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchRecogniser)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        isPerformingSegue = false
    }

    func pinched(recogniser: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        if recogniser.scale <= 0.2 && !isPerformingSegue {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindSegue", sender: self)
            isPerformingSegue = true
        }
    }
}
```